# Fill screen with cells in datagrid depending on size of screen

Tags: c#, datagrid, size, scale, cells

I have put a datagridview into my windows form. I measure width and height of the screen and then I draw empty cells on the screen. That works fine, problem is that I don't know how much cells I can put on my screen depending on width and height. I get a lot more cells then I should. When I draw them I'am getting more cells than size of my screen on my right and on the bottom of my screen.

I'll put some code so you can see what I am talking about:

```
public static int height= Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
public static int width= Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;

public void draw()
{
    number_of_cells_width = width/ 5;  //I have put number 5 because I think they are 5x5 by default size
    number_of_cells_height = height / 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_cells_width ; i++)
    {
        grid.Columns.Add("", "");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_cells_height ; i++)
    {
        grid.Rows.Add("");
    }
}
```

And I have put datagridview to fill my parent.
So I get a lot more cells then I should. Any idea how to fix this?

I think some dividing should do the job. But I don't see what I have done wrong.

Thank you

Comment: 1. PrimatyScreen.Bounds is all area including taskbar. 2. Forms with borders size is smaller than screen area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width` Does not take into account the windows title bars etc ...

So you will have to take these elements into account if you want to use this method. Or simply get the size of your DataGridView, and calculate from there ?

`DatagridView1.Height` and  `DatagridView1.Width` should come in handy.

Then just put the code in the correct event, so that you reajust when the window gets resized :)

Edit : the event `Resize` of the `datagridView` should suit your needs :)

Edit 2 :

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in DataGridView1.Columns) 
{
    col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
    col.Width = 5;
}
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows) 
{
    row.Height = 5;
}
```

The following snippet should parse all columns and rows and set their size to 5. So you will have cells 5*5 and columns which dont autosize

Comment: I want to start in a full screen. I put for example: `int a = grid.Height/5;
            int b = grid.Width/5;` and then I draw grid. But screen is not fully filled. How can I check what is a height and width of one cell so I can devide by that. Maybe it's not 5x5

Comment: Change the WindowState of your form to Maximized to startup full screen

Comment: default cell size is `height of default font plus 9 pixels x 100 pixels`. Its default row height and default column width.

Comment: I have put Maximized and still has same thing. I think that 5x5 is not good approach. How can I put cell height and width into for example some variable.

Comment: Oh, well yes, maybe 5*5 is not the default size ! The size of cells depend a lot, make sure the autosize is disable, and make sure you set the width/height to what you want !

Comment: I have tried your code. When I put `int a = grid.Height/5;` It draws only like 2/3 of the width and more height then full screen. I can go down the screen. When I put `int a=grid.Height;` then I get more then full screen.

Comment: What exactly is your grid ? You might need to take into account the height/width of headers if have any ! I cant tell from here what is wrong, but I think its something really basic

Comment: yes I agree with you. It's really something basic. I don't have headers. I mean I don't know if approach is right. Is  `int a = grid.Height/5;` right thing to do when my cell is 5x5?

Comment: Well if the cell is 5*5, and that you can visually see that you dont have any other elements to take into account, yes. But maybe you have separators between cells ? You would  have to take those into account too.